# Best Practise for Software Build and Deployment

Tags: maven, gradle, ant

What are best practise you guys are using in your Project.

Currently I am using Ant scripts to do some chores for project building, then Maven.
Currently we don't have any direct pipelines for CI/CD but I want to know how industry is moving and shaping. I tried Gradle and find it cool.

So please Elaborate what you guys think could be the best practise if some company is going to develop from scratch!

Answer (score 1):

First things first, IMO this question is not really suitable to SO format where people ask concrete questions about concrete technologies. This question is too broad.

Regarding the build tools you've mentioned in the question:

I would say that with both Maven and Gradle you can achieve descent modern pipeline, on the other hand you can develop awful gradle and maven ( to some extent ) scripts that will become a nightmare to maintain. Ant is rather outdated these dates so I wouldn't pick it for a new project.

Ant/Maven/Gradle are only build tools, proper CI/CD has so much more than that.

Depending on the type of your application you'll probably would like to learn about:

- git
- nexus/artifactory
- Jenkins or other CI tool
- Testing - this is a very broad topic
- docker
- kubernetes & proper deployment on kubernetes
- proper logging
- proper metering
- and so on and so forth

If you're planning to run on cloud than you'll obviously have to learn what your cloud provide has to offer.

One last idea I would like to stress is that there is no such a thing as a "one proper pipeline" - every company builds the CI/CD pipeline that works for them best.
Of course some pipelines are similar but they don't really have to be identical, and its OK, because:

- Some companies are small some are large
- Some release a many times a day, some opt for 1/2 year release
- Some work only with Java (I understand you've primarily meant java ecosystem in the question) - other also use other languages that have to somehow work together
- Some use their own server, others host the application the cloud (here again, one goes to AWS, other to Google Cloud or Microsoft Azure, or maybe other cloud provider)
- And so on and so forth

Comment: Thanks @markbramnik for taking time to write. and Yeah I do understand its a Broad question and I hv posted it on other platform also to get the best out of the collective knowledge.